# How do I use RANDBETWEEN for 2 ranges of numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to use RANDBETWEEN for 2 ranges of numbers?

Perhaps something like:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(0,9 [and] 18,23)
```

This, way it can scan both ranges before spitting out a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(RANDBETWEEN(0,15)<10,RANDBETWEEN(0,9),RANDBETWEEN(18,23))
```

The first randbetween gives you a random number for the total digits in each range.  Burying it in and if function allows you to split the result on equal probability by setting the cut off at the first possible digit count in the next range.  Once the range case has been decided, a randbetween of the appropriate range is performed.

Note this will only work for 2 ranges. If you have 3 or more ranges you would need to perform the first randbtween in its own cell, then in a second cell do the nested IF functions as required.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is probably the following:

```
=LET(Value,RANDBETWEEN(0,15),IF(Value<10,Value,Value+8))
```

Comment: I understand the concept you are putting forth, but that is not an excel formula as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ForwardEd It is, but the [`LET`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function was a recent addition.

Comment: ah I am using Excel 2013 so it was not coming up as an option.  Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score -1):

I found something that worked for this:

=IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,2)=1,RANDBETWEEN(0,9),RANDBETWEEN(18,23))

Comment: That biases 18-23 over 0-9.

Comment: @Phylogenesis can you explain why?

Comment: There are 10 digits in the first case, and 6 digits in the second case.  Each case has equal probability of coming up.  but the chance of a digit coming up from the first case is 1 in 10, where as the chance for a digit coming up in the second case is 1 in 6 so they are not equal odds.  Therefore a bias.

Comment: Another way to look at it is to take the example to the extreme.  lets say the range of numbers in case one was 1 to 1000000000,  and the number is the second range is just -1.  The odds of -1 coming up are 50%.  Much higher probability of getting -1 than any other digit.

Comment: @Euler'sDisgracedStepchild does that explanation work?

Comment: @BPmkt  your formula only works fairly (equal probability) if the number of digits in each range are equal.

Comment: Forward Ed yes, makes sense thanks. @BPmkt based on your other recent question, I assume you do not care about bias in this sense? Perhaps you should specify with an edit to your question.